# Regular beep on Dell poweredge server

Tags: dell

An old Dell PowerEdge Server from a friend started to emit a loud an annoying beep every few seconds.
There is no special rythm to the beep, no variety in pitch, length or rythm.

The funny thing is: the server is running. When I shut it down, the beeping stops, when I restart the computer it will start beeping after a few seconds, even though it is still showing the BIOS screen.

I checked the event log but found no error messages which might explain the beeps.

The computer is running Windows 2000 Server and is loooong out of support, obviously.

How do I find whats wrong with the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have degraded raid.  If you want to continue running with a degraded raid volume, you can disable this beeping via the management software in whatever OS you're on.

Comment: If your controller complains about an error in your RAID, you **fix** it, not tell it to shut up!

Comment: In some environments immediate replacement is not an option (especially on a number of older Dell poweredge servers that don't have hot swap drive bays).  Once you're alerted that it needs to be fixed, you generally would tell it to shut up if you're not immediately fixing it.  Do you not acknowledge alerts prior to fixing them?

Comment: The beeping already occurs during POST, when no OS is started yet - so the warning probably would be needed to be switched off in the RAID BIOS, not the OS?

Comment: And I wholeheartedly agree with switching off this infernal noise while waiting for the hdd to be delivered.

Comment: @Sam - I'm not sure if the alert beeps can be disabled via the RAID BIOS, it's never been an option as the only time I'd take such servers down were to actually replace the drive (no hot swap bays on some of the older poweredge servers I use to have to deal with).  I do know that you can disable the beep on the raid controller via the Windows-based Administration Utility for it.

Comment: Thats ok, the hdd arrived so the sound problem is gone, too. Thanks for the info!!

Answer (score 4):

Failing cooling or dead power supply are the most likely candidates. In the bios, check the temperature display. For PSU failures, see if this server has redundant PSUs and if one of them shows a red light or no light at all.

Comment: POST says 'one logical Drive degraded'. Bios Hot no temp Display. Guess Raid Gas a Problem.

Comment: Yes, this will be it. Replace the disk as soon as possible.